# Same order groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question regarding the following proof that shows that every group of prime order is cyclic.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $p$ be prime and $G$ be a group such that $|G|=p$. Then contains more than one element. Let $g\in G$ such that $g\neq 1$. Then $\langle g\rangle$ contains more than one element. Since $\langle g\rangle\leqslant G$, by Lagrange's theorem, $|\langle g\rangle|$ divides $p$. Since $|\langle g\rangle|>1$ and $|\langle g\rangle|$ divides a prime, $|\langle g\rangle|=p=|G|$. Hence, $\langle g\rangle=G$. It follows that $G$ is cyclic.$\blacksquare$

---

> - My question is regarding this statement: $|\langle g\rangle|=p=|G|$.  Hence, $\langle g\rangle=G$.
> - Why this statement is true? We can find a lot example different groups with same orders.
> - $\Bbb Z_4$ and Klein $4$-group have same order but different.
> - $\langle(123)\rangle\neq \langle(124)\rangle$ in $A_4$ but 
>     both are prime order $3$.
> - Could it be set theory property. Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets such that $|A|=|B|$. If $A\subset B$ then $A=B$.

Comment: $\langle g\rangle$ is a subset of $G$ and it has the same number of elements as $G$. This means they coincide. In your two examples, there is no inclusion but only equality of the orders.

Comment: $<g>\subset G$ it is obvious. Can we show that $G\subset <g>$ as a elementary.

Comment: To show that $G\subset <g>$, the proof argues that $|G|=|<g>|$.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly my question.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716081/subset-with-same-cardinality) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304235/set-theory-cardinality-of-a-subset-of-a-finite-set)

Comment: I add  it my question  before your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your final bullet point is the answer: $| \langle g \rangle | = |G|$ and $\langle g \rangle \subseteq G$ together imply that $\langle g \rangle = G$.